# Is it possible to calculate a public key from the message hash and signature?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Is it possible to calculate a public key from the message hash and signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to create *a* public key from the signature. It will be equivalent to the key used to generate the signature but not necessarily identical.

You can find an example implementation [here](https://github.com/ScripterRon/BitcoinCore/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ScripterRon/BitcoinCore/ECKey.java#L595-L615).

Comment: I think you not right

Comment: I guess that's possible. Do you have some reason to think that I'm not right? Or maybe [this link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18105/how-does-recovering-the-public-key-from-an-ecdsa-signature-work/18106#18106) will convince you. Or perhaps section 4.1.6 of [this link](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf).

Comment: proove it please

Comment: Read David's links.

Comment: so the answer is ... `yes` or `not`?

Comment: Read David's answer.

Answer (score 0):

[BIP143](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki) implies it is possible per the [No FindAndDelete](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki#no-findanddelete) example.

I think the following pseudocode would do it

```python
pubkey = get_pubkey(generate_key())
while not verify_sig(signature, pubkey, msg_hash):
  pubkey = get_pubkey(generate_key())
```

and as David suggested, I suppose not necessarily identical but equivalent for signature verification purposes.